# Update Statement with Inline SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

This syntax keeps giving me an invalid column.  All I want to do is insert the value into the table.  How should I change my syntax to make it possible? This is the error presented.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Alpha12'.

Code:

```
Declare @vector varchar(25), @sql varchar(max)
Set @vector = 'Alpha12'

Create Table #Test (vector varchar(50))     

Set @sql = 'Update  #Test '
       + 'set vector = coalesce(''' + @vector + ''', '''')'

Print @sql
Exec (@sql)

Select * from #Test

Drop Table #Test
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by repeatedly rolling back your question, but please stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape your interpolated `varchar` variable `@vector` with single quotes and use `insert` instead of `update` statement:

```
set @sql = 'insert into  #Test '
         + 'values (coalesce(''' + @vector + ''', ''''))'
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68b32/506)

Comment: this removes the error I was receiving, but it doesn't deposit the value in vector into my table

Comment: @BigPimpin: Use `insert` instead of  `update`  then. See update demo.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use `Exec` Dynamic SQL?  It's risky because it enables sql injection.

Why not do the Insert statement normally:

```
Insert into  #Test 
Values (Coalesce(@vector,''))
```